# Not able to Connect a Remote Host to the VisualVM

Tags: monitoring, jmx, visualvm

I am new to Java and I'm facing a problem in connecting a Remote Host to the `JVisualVM`.

I've searched the Internet and followed all the steps mentioned there but still am not able to resolve the issue. The steps I followed are:

1. I started the jstatd on the remote server by first creating a `jstatd.all.policy` file in the `$JAVA_HOME/bin`. The file contained: `grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" { permission java.security.AllPermission;};`
2. I started the `Jstatd` as `jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy`
3. I started the Java application on the remote host as :

   ```
   java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false application_name
   ```
4. I then started as instance of the `JVisualVM` on my local machine and as I added the remote host, it got connected but i wasn't able to see any of the Java processes.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: it's more simple to just edit your question...

Answer (score 18):

I encountered similar problems when connecting to Glassfish application server. See solutions that worked for me as they can be same for You:

- Try setting on your application:

> -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=*Remote_Server_External_IP_Address* 
>   
>   The mentioned IP address should be server external IP (may sound silly but it worked for me). The main problem in my case was JMX pointing to the localhost and looping. In config files the exact IP address should be set to the remote host. I described it as 'Problem 2' In [my blog: handling connection problems](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/setting-up-glassfish-monitoring/)

- If Firewall block is an issue then I recommend trying XMing with SSH tunnel (which is simple to set). Here is instruction, if You encounter problems setting it:
  [Remote use of VisualVM with Xming (my blog)](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/remote-use-of-visualvm-with-xming/)
  Biggest advantage of using XMing is that it will work almost always when SSH is enabled. You just have to place VisualVM files on the remote host and run it from command line. XWindow will show VisualVM Window on Your local computer.
- There is a chance that it is VisualVM issue - try using some other tool just to verify what is wrong. I recommend **JConsole**. It works similar to VisualVM and I also described details on [my blog](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/jvm-monitoring-for-glassfish/)

Answer (score 13):

You need to start jstatd with the additional option that points to the server's external IP or hostname:

```
statd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=my_server_ip/hostname
```

Answer based on: https://java.net/projects/visualvm/lists/users/archive/2010-03/message/8

Comment: Thanks, the `java.rmi.server.hostname` is what finally got it working for me.

Answer (score 8):

To connect to a remote VM **you have to start that remote VM with specific options**:

```
java
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
class
```

After the VM is started, go to your VisualVM and do the following:

1. File -> Add JMX Connection
2. Type: *yourHostName:9000* and click OK
3. On the left you will have the added JMX connection, double click on it and that's it!

*More details on the **Java Monitoring and Management Platform** can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/index.html).*

Comment: I executed the java application using the steps you mentioned, but its still not showing any java processes under the remote host i added. When i try to add a jmx connection it gives the following error in the log file: **connect(service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://10.88.36.146:9000/jmxrmi) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: **

Comment: check the firewall on both machines... maybe the traffic over port 9000 is not allowed...

Comment: I have disabled the firewall on my local machine and the IP table settings on the remote host are :                                 `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                     target prot opt source destination                              Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)                                    target prot opt source destination                             Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                    target prot opt source destination`

Comment: which OS is running on the remote machine, Linux?

Comment: Yes..I am using Linux version 2.6.18-164.el5PAE

Comment: google a bit to find out how to see which ports are allowed, and then how to allow a port (9000 in your case)... or, if you don't run something on known ports (80, 22, 443) - start the VM with that port...

Comment: I think it is a firewall problem. To test it, disable firewall on the remote host. Note also that it not enough to open port 9000, JMX uses additional dynamically allocated port for communication.

Comment: I have completely disabled the firewall on my remote system using:                                                                                                                                  # /etc/init.d/iptables save                                         # /etc/init.d/iptables stop                                         But still i am not able to see any Java processe. Its making me go nuts :(

Comment: Please, update your post with the command by which you start your java program. Tnx.

Comment: Could you bypass the first two steps and just start the java program with given arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to do this:

1. Launch an [ejstatd](https://github.com/anthony-o/ejstatd) in your remote host this way (in ejstatd folder): `mvn exec:java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<remote_host_name> -Dexec.args="-pr 1099 -ph 1100 -pv 1101"` (used for "jstatd" type connection) (only specify `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname` if the hostname of your remote host does not match with the one you are seeing from your local network)
2. Launch your Java application with those additional Java parameters: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1102 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1102 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<remote_host_name>` (used for "JMX" type connection) (same remark as the previous point for `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname`)
3. Open those 4 ports on your remote host and make them available to your local machine: `1099`, `1100`, `1101` and `1102`
4. Launch JVisualVM

   1. Right-click on "Remote" > "Add Remote Host..." and enter your remote host name in "Host name" (if you don't use the port `1099`, you can change this in the "Advanced Settings")
   2. Right-click on the remote host you've just created > "Add JMX Connection..." and enter "`<remote_host_name>:1102`" in "Connection" input, and check "Do not require SSL connection"
   3. Your Java process will appear twice: one from the "jstatd" connection type, and one from the "JMX" connection type.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the open source [ejstatd](https://github.com/anthony-o/ejstatd) tool.

Answer (score 2):

Start [jstatd](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstatd.html) in [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) on the server which needs to be monitored and connect `VisualVM` to the jstatd port, following below steps:

**Step 1** : Create `start-jstatd.sh` and copy the below content:

```
nohup jstatd -p 1099 -J-Djava.security.policy=<(echo 'grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {permission java.security.AllPermission;};') &
```

**Step 2:** Give executable permission to the file:

```
$ chmod a+rwx start-jstatd.sh
```

**Step 3:** Start jstatd:

```
$ sh start-jstatd.sh
```

**Step 4:** Add Remote Host in `VisualVM`:

[image]

**Step 5:** Add **JMX Connection** to the **Remote Host**, as shown in the below image and Click OK button:
[image]