# Attach to remote (not local) VM

Tags: java, jvm, jmx

Java Attach API can attach to local VMs and load agents to it. How can I attach to VM on another computer to load agent ?

I know about JMX. But I didn't find out how load my custom agent to remote VM.

Maybe there are exist another ways to solve my problem (to load and execute custom code (agent) to remote VM) ?

upd. I want to execute custom code on remote JVM. Independence of initial JVM parameters is plus.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the original problem you need to solve in this way?

Comment: attachment, monitoring and code update at remote running clean JVMs

Comment: I will strongly discourage using agents for updating software. Just imagine the support problems you can get on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found experimental solution: *jsadebugd*.
Then you can attach to it by *sun.jvm.hotspot.jdi.SAPIDAttachingConnector* connector.

Comment: Did u solve this in a program?  @Andrew Knodratovich

Comment: I have same problem with you. How to attach a remote jvm and inject code using program without restarting the remote jvm to add some debug arguments?

Answer (score 2):

It's no problem running a application server (Tomcat) in production, even with [remote debugging attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871723/not-able-to-connect-a-remote-host-to-the-visualvm/7885695#7885695).

UPDATE

If you want to execute custom code inside your app, then one solution would be to write a class and compile it, store it somewhere on the server, and then inside your app execute some method like this:

```
/**
 * This method:
 * <li>loads a class from the server file system
 * <li>does a lookup for the method to execute
 * <li>creates a new instance of the specified class
 * <li>executes the given method with the given arguments
 *     (which can be null if the method doesn't have arguments)
 * <li>returns the result of the invoked method
 * 
 * @param classUrlOnTheServer
 * @param className
 * @param methodNameToExecute
 * @param argumentsForTheMethod arguments that should be passed to
 *                              the method of the loaded class - can
 *                              be null.
 * @return returns the result of the invoked method
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 * @throws SecurityException
 * @throws NoSuchMethodException
 * @throws InstantiationException
 * @throws IllegalAccessException
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 * @throws InvocationTargetException
 */
public static Object loadAndExecuteCustomMethodFromALoadedClass(String classUrlOnTheServer,
                                                        String className,
                                                        String methodNameToExecute,
                                                        Object ... argumentsForTheMethod)
                                                                                        throws ClassNotFoundException,
                                                                                        MalformedURLException,
                                                                                        SecurityException,
                                                                                        NoSuchMethodException,
                                                                                        InstantiationException,
                                                                                        IllegalAccessException,
                                                                                        IllegalArgumentException,
                                                                                        InvocationTargetException {
   File file = new File(classUrlOnTheServer);
   URL url = file.toURI().toURL();  
   URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
   ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
   Class clazz = cl.loadClass(className);

   Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodNameToExecute);
   Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
   Object result = method.invoke(instance, argumentsForTheMethod);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: I need to inject custom code. With JMX I can get information about remote JVM, but I can't to inject and execute code. Attach API provide ways to load executable agent in JVM, but only local JVM. I'm looking for the way to do the same with remote JVM.

Comment: With remote debugging you can evaluate expressions (whole lines of code). You can't save that code, but you can change values of fields and variables. I don't fully understand what you want't, can you please edit you initial question and explain in details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, do you just want to connect to a remote VM? When connected you can execute whatever you want, event terminate the VM.
You have to start your VM in debug mode :

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n

Then in Eclipse for example, create a new remote application profile. check this :
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html

Comment: I know about debug interfaces, but I need this for production, not for debug.